# ClassCastException on using Appium TouchActions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, appium, ui-automation, java-client

Im trying to perform tap action using Appium TouchActions class, but it throws exceptions. Please provide your solution.

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
===========================================================
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String title = driver.findElement(By.id("app_title")).getText();
        System.out.println("TITLE: " + title);
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("bt1"));
        TouchActions touch = new TouchActions(driver);
        touch.singleTap(ele);
        touch.perform();
```

Output and Exception:

```
Aug 02, 2018 6:51:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
TITLE: TestApp
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions.<init>(TouchActions.java:38)
at scratchpad.MobileAutomation.main(MobileAutomation.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Version Used:
**selenium-java: 3.11.0**
**java-client(io.appium): 5.0.4**

Let me know, if you want any other information.
Also give me suggestion best way to perform Mobile operation such as swipe(all direction), tap, double tap, long press, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of WebElement consider using MobileElement or AndroidElement

Comment: touch.singleTap(ele); takes only WebElement only, not MobileElement or AndroidElement. So whats point you are comming to say sir?

Answer (score 1):

Use Appium `TouchAction` instead of Selenium `TouchActions`. It is also handful to put the below code into parent of your test class:

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new TouchAction(driver);

public void tap(MobileElement element) {

  getTouchAction()
    .tap(
      new TapOptions().withElement(
        ElementOption.element(
          element)))
    .perform();
}
```

Call the method ():

```
tap(myMobileElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with that you can use TouchAction
here is an example

```
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
        t.tap(TapOptions.tapOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(webElementForExpandibleList))).perform();
```