# The method tap(TapOptions) is undefined for the type TouchActions

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.TapOptions.tapOptions;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;

public class Gestures extends Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();      
        TouchActions t = new TouchActions(driver);
        WebElement expandList = 
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView(@Text='android.widget.TextView')");
        t.tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandList)));
    }
}
```

Under the `object tap`, there appears a red line saying that:   The method tap(TapOptions) is undefined for the type TouchActions
    [TapObjectIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G7pH.png)

Answer (score 0):

For org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions, there is no any **tap** method.

You can use **singleTap()** instead of tap().

You can check all the available method for TouchActions [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/touch/TouchActions.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out:

I wrote this line as shared to me by the instructor:

>new TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandList))).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(250))).perform();

and now it's coming up with this error:

>( The method waitOptions(Duration) is undefined for the type Gestures)

How to resolve this one?

Comment: O yes, I resolved this by importing:
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions.waitOptions;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
  WebElement expandList = 
       driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView(@Text='android.widget.TextView')");

    TouchActions t = new TouchActions(driver);
    t.singleTap(expandList);
    t.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to execute the code this way:

> without creating or using any object for TouchAction and TapOptions, it worked the way shown below. earlier, the code was finding the first element (Views) and till .click() it got worked but the tap wasn't getting read by Appium. With the help of these links ([Error while trying out touch actions using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303679/error-while-trying-out-touch-actions-using-appium)) && ([ClassCastException on using Appium TouchActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655230/classcastexception-on-using-appium-touchactions)), I somehow managed to make changes in my code and they worked great.

Moreover, in 2nd last line of code,

> TouchActions is underlined in yellow(warning) color that says "TouchAction is a raw type. References to generic type TouchAction should be parameterized"  I still want to know how these and similar warnings can be resolved though.

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.TapOptions.tapOptions;

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions.waitOptions;

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.time.Duration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class Gestures extends Parent {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

AndroidDriver driver = Capabilities();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text= 'Views']").click();

//to do Taps on device, Appium_team have made class = TouchActions

TapOptions t = new TapOptions();

WebElement expandList= driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']");

new TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandList))).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(250))).perform();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    } }

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public class LongPressDemo extends AppiumBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =capabilities();

    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();
    WebElement expandablelist = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']");

    new TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandablelist))).perform();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me
public class LongPressDemo extends AppiumBasic {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =capabilities();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();
WebElement expandablelist = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']");

new TouchAction(driver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandablelist))).perform();

}
```

}